# How to change Formstone upload method from "POST" to "PUT"? Below is the code. Reference https://formstone.it/components/upload/

Tags: javascript

How to change Formstone upload method from "POST" to "PUT"? Below is the code. Reference https://formstone.it/components/upload/

The code below has options and i cant find one that changes the HTTP request of the action from post to put.

```
Formstone.Ready(function() {
        
        $.upload("defaults", {
            options:{
                method:'PUT',
                type:'PUT',
            }
        });
        
        $(".upload").upload({
        //  action: REST_DOCUMENTS_UPLOAD
            action: WEBRET_UPLOAD_FILE_URL,
            headers: {
             'Authorization': ssoToken,
             },
            maxSize: 1073741824,
            beforeSend: onBeforeSend,
            autoUpload: false
        }).on("start.upload", onStart)
            .on("complete.upload", onComplete)
            .on("filestart.upload", onFileStart)
            .on("queued.upload", onQueued)
            .on("fileprogress.upload", onFileProgress)
            .on("filecomplete.upload", onFileComplete)
            .on("fileerror.upload", onFileError);
    //  .on("chunkstart.upload", onChunkStart)
    //  .on("chunkprogress.upload", onChunkProgress)
    //  .on("chunkcomplete.upload", onChunkComplete)
    //  .on("chunkerror.upload", onChunkError)


        $(".filelist.queue").on("click", ".cancel", onCancel);
        // $(".filelist.queue").on("click", ".remove", onRemove);
        //$(".cancel_all").on("click", onCancelAll);
        $(".start-upload").on("click", onStart);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is [hardcoded to use POST](https://github.com/Formstone/Formstone/blob/master/src/js/upload.js#L534) so, short of editing the source code of the library, you can't.